# Where should I post my Office 365 SharePoint related questions?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

What are the good forums to post Office 365 SharePoint developer related questions?

Thank you,

Answer (score 3):

Either here or stackexchange.com I would say.

Comment: Be sure to include the ms-office tag, that's the tag the Office Dev team watches (at least on StackOverflow).

Answer (score 1):

apart from the Stackexchange, you can visit the MSFT own technet forum.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/home?forum=sharepointdevelopment

or 365 community. https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154

Answer (score 1):

One more to the list.
[Yammer Office 365 network](https://www.yammer.com/itpronetwork/). Better to post the question on StackExchange and share it there for more audience if no response from here.